# How to wire an LMD18200 and an arduino?

Tags: h-bridge, wires

Ive been working with a motor project for a while and i bought this H-bridge(LMD18200). I dont understand how im supposed to connect it to the arduino.

Here is the datasheet for the lmd18200:

[image: the datasheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most basic way would be to use only DIR, PWM and Break.

Use Break as enable (put high at begining of the program, put low when you want to start rotation).

Use Dir to change rotation of the motor (usually high is CV, low is CCV, but you need to check the datasheet)

And hook up PWM to [PWM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM) pin on arduino. This will control the speed.

Comment: Do i just put the break and dir in any digital port?

Comment: yes, any output. 
If you want to monitor thermal and current later on connect those to the input

Comment: To the *analog* inputs (A0 to A5 on the uno)

Comment: @jms they are in use. What do i do with tf and sen?

Comment: @Marc Sorry, I was confusing. The TF is just a binary output and can be connected to any IO pin configured as a digital input, but if you want to measure current you do need to connect CSEN to an analog input. You can still drive the motor without connecting TF or CSEN at all, they are optional.